# If condition inside foreach to know all matches

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have this `$fields` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => Name
            [condition] => 0
            [value] => abc
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [input] => Username
            [condition] => 1
            [value] => xyz
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [input] => Email
            [condition] => 1
            [value] => xyz@gmail.com
        )
    ...
)
```

condition 0 is equals to and condition 1 is is not equals to. How can i note that all the matches.

I need to echo something if only all of the condition matches. I mean `if value is abc for name and value is not xyz for username and value is not xyz@gmail.com for email field.`.

```
foreach( $fields as $field ) {
   if( $field['condition'] == 0 ) {
       if( $field['value'] == 'value_from_input') {
           echo 'something';       
       }
    }
    elseif( $field['condition'] == 0 ) {
      if( $field['value'] == 'value_from_input') {
           echo 'something';       
       }
   } 
}
```

However this seems to be OR condition, if any matches there is a echo. I need all the conditions to match.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Keep a flag set to true, then loop through the array and when there's a codition that does not match, set the flag to false and break out of the loop. If the flag is still true after the loop, you can be sure that all the conditions matched:

```
$fields = [
    [
        "field" => "Name",
        "condition" => 0,
        "value" => "abc",
    ],
    [
        "field" => "Username",
        "condition" => 1,
        "value" => "abc",
    ],
    [
        "field" => "Email",
        "condition" => 1,
        "value" => "abc",
    ],
];
$success = true;
foreach( $fields as $field ) {
   if ($field["condition"] === 0) {
       $success = false;
       break;
   }
}
if ($success) { 
    echo "All conditions match";
}
else {
    echo "Some conditions don't match";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MNYEk)

There's actually lots of ways you can do this. Another one would be to filter the fields where the condition doesn't match, and then compare the `count`s of each array:

```
$filtered = array_filter($fields, function($el) {
    return $el["condition"] === 0;
});
$success = count($fields) === count($filtered);
if ($success) { 
    echo "All conditions match";
}
else {
    echo "Some conditions don't match";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that seems to be a logic. but I need to check `if Name is abc && username isnot abc && email isnot abc@gmail.com` like situation.

Comment: Oh, I don't quite understand then. How many elements are there? What's the logic behind your conditions?